# Calculating discharge on the pipe diameter and the pressure?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure, speed

Is it possible to сalculate discharge / flow rate on the pipe diameter and the pressure (for constant pressure)?

For example:

[image]

`Pressure_internal = 5 bar`, `Diameter_pipe = 36 mm`, `Density_water = 1000 kg/m^3`

Bernoulli's Formula [(online calculation)](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sqrt%28%285-1%29%5Bbar%5D+*+2+%2F+%281000+%5Bkg%2Fm%5E3%5D%29%29+to+%5Bm%2Fs%5D):

$$\frac{\rho v^2}{2} + \rho g h + p = const$$

$$v \approx \sqrt{(p_i-p_a)\frac{2}{\rho_w}} = \sqrt{(5 \mathrm{bar}-1 \mathrm{bar})\frac{2}{1000 \frac{\mathrm{kg}}{\mathrm{m}^3} }}=28.284 \frac{\mathrm{m}}{\mathrm{s}}$$

Then the discharge should be [(online calculation)](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=pi%20*%20%2818%5Bmm%5D%20%29%5E2%20*%2028.284%5Bm%2Fs%5D%20to%20%5Bl%2Fmin%5D):

$$Q = Sv = (\pi r^2) v = \pi * (18\mathrm{mm})^2 *28.284\frac{\mathrm{m}}{\mathrm{s}} = 1717.81 \frac{\mathrm{l}}{\mathrm{min}}$$

But these values are very far from reality. How can I perform a calculation correct?

Comment: If you are asking for help in doing a calculation, first you need to state the conditions of the problem. It is difficult to comment without understanding what the situation is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's called a *Poiseuille flow*, if the flow is laminar its given [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hagen%E2%80%93Poiseuille_equation).

If the flow is turbulent then your approach with Bernoulli should be correct.

If its in between then its more complicated, you can use a semi empirical [Darcy type law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darcy%E2%80%93Weisbach_equation).

Answer (score 1):

There are many online calculators available to do this kind of thing. For example I found [this one](http://www.tlv.com/global/TI/calculator/water-pressure-loss-through-piping.html) that gives the pressure drop when the flow rate is given. Playing around a bit until it gave a pressure drop of (almost) 4 bar gave the following:

[image]
[image]

As you can see, taking account of real world effects (in particular the viscous drag from the wall) gives us a flow rate of ~1000 liter per minute. That is fast - but then 36 mm is a big pipe, and the flow velocity of 16 m/s is not unreasonable. Pointing the outlet of this pipe up in the air, such a jet of water could reach about 12 m high - considerably less than the 40 m head of water needed to generate the 4 bar of excess pressure. This makes sense as an order of magnitude.

Answer (score 0):

If you are approximating the fluid as being inviscid (which apparently is the case if you are using Bernoulli), the pressure drop in a section of pipe of constant diameter must be zero, irrespective of the flow rate.  So the upstream pressure in the pipe could not be 5 bars if the downstream pressure is 1 bar.  Either both pressures are 5 bars or both pressures are 1 bar.  Your equation implicitly assumes that the upstream velocity is zero (which is not the case).